# Term for node measure of flow importance

Tags: graph-theory, networks

I'm looking for a term describing measures that relate to the importance of nodes/vertices in a graph in controlling flow. Nodes that sits in between dense clusters would be scored highly while highly connected nodes in the centre of clusters would be scored lower as there're lots of alternative routes around them. A measure I would put in this category is Burts Constraint.

While the obvious answer would be "centrality" I'm unsure if this term is generally reserved for measures that scores highly connected (i.e. central) nodes highest.

Comment: Your example would be better for betweenness centrality than for other centrality metrics.